# Agrupar widgets vertical y horizontalmente en un layout

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, pyqt4

Estoy haciendo un framework en python y Qt, y tengo una duda. A ver si con algo de ayuda puedo solucionarlo.

Mi duda es la siguiente: a la hora de hacer un layout quiero que algunos botones formen un layout vertical y otros un layout horizontal, de esta manera no se haría demasiado grande la pantalla y estaría todo más organizado. Por ahora solo soy capaz de crear un tipo de layout vertical y añadir todo a éste.

Me gustaría hacerlo todo en una clase, porque este layout forma parte de un `StackedWidget` y dependiendo del boton seleccionado, en pantalla se mostrará uno u otro (que será otra clase diferente).

Esto es lo que tengo ahora:

[image: Layout actual]

Pero quisiera algo así:

[image: Layout deseado]

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
class propiedades_ueye_class(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(propiedades_ueye_class, self).__init__(parent)
        self.foto = QtGui.QPushButton('Foto')
        self.preview = QtGui.QPushButton('Preview')
        self.distancia = QtGui.QPushButton('Distancia')
        self.livemode = QtGui.QPushButton('Live mode')
        self.timelapse = QtGui.QPushButton('TimeLapse')
        self.ejex = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.ejey = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.segundos= QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.nfotos = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.lejex = QtGui.QLabel("Eje X")
        self.lejey = QtGui.QLabel("Eje Y")
        self.lsegundos = QtGui.QLabel("Segundos")
        self.lfotos = QtGui.QLabel("Fotos")
        self.centrado = QtGui.QCheckBox("Centrado")
        self.mallado = QtGui.QCheckBox("Mallado")
        self.definido = QtGui.QCheckBox("Definido")
        self.reticulo = QtGui.QCheckBox("Reticulo")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lejex)
        layout.addWidget(self.ejex)
        layout.addWidget(self.lejey)
        layout.addWidget(self.ejey)
        layout.addWidget(self.centrado)
        layout.addWidget(self.mallado)
        layout.addWidget(self.definido)
        layout.addWidget(self.foto)
        layout.addWidget(self.preview)
        layout.addWidget(self.distancia)
        layout.addWidget(self.livemode)
        layout.addWidget(self.reticulo)
        layout.addWidget(self.lsegundos)
        layout.addWidget(self.segundos)
        layout.addWidget(self.lfotos)
        layout.addWidget(self.nfotos)
        layout.addWidget(self.timelapse)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: ¿Alvaro podrias explicar mejor dónde quieres posicionar cada widget? Un esquema podría ser de gran ayuda... Dependiendo de como quieras posicionar podrias usar dos layouts o un grid. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla en la primera imagen se muestra lo que da el código adjuntos,  y en la segunda imagen es lo que estoy buscando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre tienes múltiples opciones, recuerda que puedes anidar layouts dentro de otros si lo deseas. No obstante, para tu caso creo que lo más simple es usar un `QGridLayout`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Propiedades_ueye_class(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Propiedades_ueye_class, self).__init__(parent)

        self.foto = QtGui.QPushButton('Foto')
        self.preview = QtGui.QPushButton('Preview')
        self.distancia = QtGui.QPushButton('Distancia')
        self.livemode = QtGui.QPushButton('Live mode')
        self.timelapse = QtGui.QPushButton('TimeLapse')
        self.ejex = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.ejey = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.segundos= QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.nfotos = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.lejex = QtGui.QLabel("Eje X")
        self.lejey = QtGui.QLabel("Eje Y")
        self.lsegundos = QtGui.QLabel("Segundos")
        self.lfotos = QtGui.QLabel("Fotos")
        self.centrado = QtGui.QCheckBox("Centrado")
        self.mallado = QtGui.QCheckBox("Mallado")
        self.definido = QtGui.QCheckBox("Definido")
        self.reticulo = QtGui.QCheckBox("Reticulo")

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lejex, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ejex, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lejey, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ejey, 1, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.centrado, 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mallado, 2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.definido, 2, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.foto, 3, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.preview, 4, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.distancia, 5, 1, 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lsegundos, 6, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.segundos, 6, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lfotos, 7, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.nfotos, 7, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.livemode, 8, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.reticulo, 9, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.timelapse, 9, 2)



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Propiedades_ueye_class()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Básicamente creamos un ***GridLayout*** de 10 filas y 3 columnas. Lo único que hay que tener en cuenta es el método [`QGridLayout.addWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-3) y sus argumentos:

```
QGridLayout.addWidget (self,
                       QWidget,
                       int row,
                       int column,
                       int rowSpan,
                       int columnSpan,
                       Qt.Alignment alignment = 0)
```

En este caso se usa `columnSpan` para aquellos widgets que ocupan más de una columna.

No se si he colocado cada widget donde debe ir ya que tu segunda imágen es más genérica que la primera, no obstante la idea es esa.

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]